# I am using moviepy to edit video clips, but there is an error that is thrown to me 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Tags: python

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoClip("C:/Users/Graphics Computer/OneDrive/Desktop/Animation_project/Scene_1.mp4")
```

when I run the above code, I get this error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error itself says it. `VideoClip` is a string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to load use **VideoFileClip** class of moviepy instead of **VideoClip**
like

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
clip = VideoFileClip("C:/Users/Graphics Computer/OneDrive/Desktop/Animation_project/Scene_1.mp4")
```

Now you can edit your video after using **clip**.

Comment: Can please mark the answer as right and upvote it will help people who face the same problem in future.